# sql inner join reference a table in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below:

```
select 
    yu.Soyad, 
    mt.ICD10Kodu, 
    count(mi.ID) as AASayisi 
from 
    Muayene.Muayene mm
    join Muayene.Ilac mi 
        on mm.ID = mi.MuayeneId
    join Yetkilendirme.Users yu 
        on mi.CreatedBy = yu.ID
    join Muayene.Tani mt 
        on mm.ID = mt.MuayeneId
where 
    mm.IsDeleted <> 1 
    and mi.IsDeleted <> 1 
    and mt.IsDeleted <> 1  
group by 
    yu.Soyad, 
    mt.ICD10Kodu
```

returns the data below:

```
HALAÇ           J00 5
DEĞİRMENCİOĞLU  J00 12
GÖKALP          J02 22
DİKİLİLER       J03 14
```

but actually I need the rate of the entity not the exact number it occurs so I need to divide it like this:

```
select 
    yu.Soyad, 
    mt.ICD10Kodu, 
    count(mi.ID)/count(select * from Muayene.Muayene where ID=mm.ID) as AASayisi 
from 
    Muayene.Muayene mm
    join Muayene.Ilac mi 
        on mm.ID = mi.MuayeneId...
```

but it doesn't work. It gives the error message:

> the multipart identifier mi.ID couldn't be found

How can I make it work?

Comment: so, does the `Muayene.Ilac` table have an `ID` column?

Comment: @Lamak yes there is too many collumn I dont want make it look dirty

Comment: Is there a relationship between Yetkilendirme.Users and Muayene.Muayene tables ?

Comment: @Rainman yes, there mm.CreatedBy is foreign key(yu.ID) but why ?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like this because you are not grouping `mm.ID` field. You should calculate the counts in seperated queries and then you can join them to calculate ratio;

```
select yu.Soyad, mt.ICD10Kodu, AASayisi, MMSayisi, (cast(AASayisi as float)/cast(MMSayisi as float)) As Ratio from (
select yu.ID as YUID, yu.Soyad, mt.ICD10Kodu, count(mi.ID) as AASayisi 
from Muayene.Muayene mm
join Muayene.Ilac mi on mm.ID = mi.MuayeneId
join Yetkilendirme.Users yu on mi.CreatedBy = yu.ID
join Muayene.Tani mt on mm.ID = mt.MuayeneId
where mm.IsDeleted <> 1 and mi.IsDeleted <> 1 and mt.IsDeleted <> 1  
group by yu.ID,yu.Soyad, mt.ICD10Kodu) miCountsQuery inner join (select yu.ID as YUID,yu.Soyad, count(mm.ID) as MMSayisi 
from Muayene.Muayene mm
join Yetkilendirme.Users yu on mm.CreatedBy = yu.ID
where mm.IsDeleted <> 1  
group by yu.ID,yu.Soyad) mmCountsQuery ON miCountsQuery.YUID = mmCountsQuery.YUID
```

The query wasn't tested. Some modifications might be needed.

Comment: only problem is all ratio values are 0 since its integer, how can I make it look as doubled. for example AASayisi= 2 mmSayisi=111 iratio returns 0 here but I need 0.178

Comment: You can cast the integers to float. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your `COUNT` operations in joined queries, not a query inside your `SELECT` list.  Queries in `SELECT` lists don't work unless you're pulling exactly 1 value, which you are not doing here.  Also, you can't do mathematical operations on derived values like `COUNT()` in the same query in which you're deriving them.

So to calculate your rate you can do the below and then join it to whatever else you need using `ID`

```
select 
    a.mi_ID as ID
    , a.ct_mi / b.ct_mm as Rate
from
    (select
        mi.ID as mi_ID
        , count(mi.ID) as ct_mi
    from  [Muayene.Ilac] as mi
    group by mi.ID) as a
inner join
    (select
        mm.ID as mm_ID
        , count(mm.ID) as ct_mm
    from [Muayene.Muayene] as mm
    group by mm.ID) as b
on a.mi_ID = b.mm_ID
```